# Very small Power Query hangs excel if source table is changed

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a power query that I'm using to automatically import and filter a table in the same workbook into another sheet.

It only 120 rows, I remove inactive rows and remove a few columns.

If I go to the source table and change a single value, then refresh the query, it processes in a couple seconds. If I change almost all the values for a column (ie, swapping "Yes" to "No" and vice versa), refreshing the query will hang Excel for 30+ minutes.

What is causing this, any ideas on how to debug, or profile the issue?

Edit: here is the power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rosterTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Full Name", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, {"First Name", type text}, {"Zendesk Name", type text}, {"FT/PT", type text}, {"Atrium?", type text}, {"Lead?", type text}, {"Assigned Tier", Int64.Type}, {"Team", type text}, {"CX Type", type text}, {" Hire Date", type datetime}, {"T1 Production Date", type datetime}, {"T2 Production Date", type datetime}, {"T3 Production Date", type any}, {"Last Day of Employment", type datetime}, {"Email", type text}, {"Expected Hours/Day based on CX Type", type any}, {"Sun", type any}, {"Mon", type any}, {"Tue", type any}, {"Wed", type any}, {"Thur", type any}, {"Fri", type any}, {"Sat", type any}, {"Total PT Hours", Int64.Type}, {"Column1", type any}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Last Name", "First Name", "FT/PT", "Lead?"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Full Name", "Team", "Atrium?", "Assigned Tier", "Status", "Zendesk Name", "CX Type", " Hire Date", "T1 Production Date", "T2 Production Date", "T3 Production Date", "Last Day of Employment", "Email", "Expected Hours/Day based on CX Type", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Total PT Hours", "Column1"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"CX Type", " Hire Date", "T1 Production Date", "T2 Production Date", "T3 Production Date", "Last Day of Employment", "Email", "Expected Hours/Day based on CX Type", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Total PT Hours", "Column1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each ([Full Name] <> null and [Full Name] <> " ")),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Full Name", "Team", "Status", "Atrium?", "Assigned Tier", "Zendesk Name"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns1", each ([Status] = "Active")),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Full Name", "Team", "Atrium?", "Assigned Tier", "Status", "Zendesk Name"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns2"
```

Function in table (This determines if someone should be Active or Inactive, and updates instantly): `=IF(TRIM([@[Full Name]]) <> "", IF(AND([@[ Hire Date]] <= ProdWeekStart, OR(TRIM([@[Last Day of Employment]]) = "", [@[Last Day of Employment]] >  ProdWeekStart )), "Active", "Inactive"), "")`

If I change the table, save, and re-open the sheet. The PowerQuery is not updated. If I try and refresh it, it still hangs.

Comment: I am not sure if it matters but save the file before refreshing. You can also try saving it as `.xlsb`

Comment: What are your formulas? Nothing should cause Excel itself to hang, but inefficient queries could cause refresh to take a long time, even on tables with small results.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT I have added the power query to my post.

Comment: The function doesn't seems to have a relation to the query you have posted: The query pulls it's data from a table or named range in an Excel sheet. So please check if this is the query that is so slow. Apart from that: You can remove all but the last "reordering"-steps because it will overrule the other ones. And: I'm a bit surprised that the functions returns quickly, as it uses recursion, which is generally slow in M. Wouldn't your function also work without the @? I would think that this is the reason for performance problems.